# Wordpress if condition is or has_tag

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm trying to make an if condition if there's a tag then echo it if not just show the archive title.

```
 $title_before = '<h1 class="archive_header">';
$title_after = '</h1>';

if(is_tag('tag_description')){
    echo '<div class="archive_desc">';
        echo tag_description();
    echo '</div>';
    echo '<div class="archive_border"></div>';
} else {
    woo_archive_title( $title_before, $title_after );
}
```

I tried the code above and the tag description is not showing, though I'm not entirely sure if is_tag covers tag_description.

Comment: Have you tried looking in the [WordPress Function Reference](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_tag)?

Answer (score 0):

The [`is_tag`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_tag) function checks if a tag archive page is being displayed.

Is that what you want?

Answer (score 0):

Found my way now, I wanted !empty. So if there is no tag/archive description it only shows the title, then if exist it shows both.

```
$tag_description = tag_description();
woo_archive_title( $title_before, $title_after );

if(!empty($tag_description)){
    echo '<div class="archive_desc">' .$tag_description. '</div>';
    echo '<div class="archive_border"></div>';
} else {
    // 
}
```

Now I need to do the styling.

Comment: Although it seems like it, this shouldn't be left as an answer, if the initial problem has been solved, the question should be removed, or flagged for moderator attention.